# Why does yumdownloader download i686 files if my pc is x86_64 and also installs them?

Tags: yum, repository

I simply found out what packages were in the group:

```
 Desktop Platform
```

via

```
yum groupinfo "Desktop Platform"
```

Then I downloaded them all one by one via:

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package_name>
```

I noticed it downloaded both: `i686 & x86_64` versions of the same packages. Then when I ran:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm
```

*(within the folder where all the packages were downloaded)*

It actually installed both: `i686 & x86_64` versions of the same packages. Based on information I know, it's not suppose to do that, it's only suppose to install `x86_64`, because my system is `x86_64`, not `i686`.

Is this a mistake by `yum`, or is it suppose to be this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the switch `--archlist=x86_64` to `yumdownloader`.

#### Example

*32-bit*

```
$ yumdownloader --destdir=`pwd`/i686 --assumeyes \
     --resolve parted --archlist=i686
```

*64-bit*

```
$ yumdownloader --destdir=`pwd`/x86_64 --assumeyes \
     --resolve parted --archlist=x86_64
```

Results:

```
$ tree 
.
|-- i686
|   |-- device-mapper-libs-1.02.63-2.fc14.i686.rpm
|   |-- libblkid-2.18-4.8.fc14.i686.rpm
|   |-- libsepol-2.0.41-3.fc14.i686.rpm
|   `-- parted-2.3-5.fc14.i686.rpm
`-- x86_64
    |-- device-mapper-libs-1.02.63-2.fc14.i686.rpm
    |-- libblkid-2.18-4.8.fc14.i686.rpm
    |-- libsepol-2.0.41-3.fc14.i686.rpm
    |-- parted-2.3-5.fc14.i686.rpm
    `-- parted-2.3-5.fc14.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: @User3432423423 - thanks for the accepts. Not sure if you know this but you can also upvote in addition to accepting answers. No pressure, just letting you know.

Comment: but why x86_64 contains i686 too?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer did not work for me on RHEL7. But I could do by

```
yumdownloader ... package.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by that option until I ran into [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1045871#c2) from a maintainer on a similar bug:

> The documentation is actually inaccurate here, `--archlist` limits architectures to the given and all compatible with the given. For your use case please use the following command:
>
> ```shell
> yumdownloader -x \*i686 --archlist=x86_64 qt5-qttools
> ```

That works for me, i686 versions aren't downloaded.