# yumdownloder option required for only 64bit packages

Tags: development, openstack

What would be the command if I want to download only 64bit rpm of the packages via the `yumdownloader` command?

Example : I have 64bit arch centos6.5 and i want to upgrade some of the packages thourgh yum but when i am downloading packages, both the arch started to download. like:

```
[root@localhost nss-softokn-freebl]# yumdownloader nss-softokn-freebl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * elrepo-kernel: elrepo.mirror.angkasa.id
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.i686.rpm                                                                                                       
nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: See similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/770024/95675

Answer (score 0):

Use the --archlist flag and so:

```
--archlist=x64
```